# Mathematical algorithm for bots detecting

Tags: r, time-series, algorithms

I'm faced with the task and I need the help of senior statisticians.There are a lot of virtual gambling, for example poker, it is need to detect bots. There are a lot of fixed indicators (mouse movement, clicks and so on).How to determine whether a bot is playing or a person on the basis of these data. Is the time series analysis relevant here?
Thank you.

```
do you want to detect on the session level or on the account level - i.e. can a legit account have a bot only playing sometimes?
```

**I want on the session level**

```
Do you have any labeled data? If you don't, the problem becomes MUCH harder.
```

**The problem is that there are no labeled data, so here it is necessary to determine somehow, if they were, I would use logistic regression, but how to define bots without labeled data? Can you suggest me? Аre there any such algorithms?**

Comment: If you do not have any labelled data, then your best approach seems to be outlier detection. If any behaviour is irregular regarding reaction time, etc., then the chance are high that you found a bot.

Comment: Yet the question should be closed because it is too broad. You are welcome to back here to ask a more specific question once you setup your pipeline and have your first results.

Comment: Why the weird formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you start with some clear problem formulation:

1. do you want to detect on the session level or on the account level - i.e. can a legit account have a bot only playing sometimes?
2. Do you have any labeled data? If you don't, the problem becomes MUCH harder. Even a couple hundred sessions hand-labeled as bot sessions should work.
3. Think about and talk with your engineers about other features you might use - such as IP, OS on which the client is run, etc. etc.

I'd start with just a simple classifier, if you have satisfied 2. If you do have labeled examples, just take those, a *lot* of unlabeled examples (which are probably not bots), and fit a simple classifier (such as logistic regression).

Only once you have a simple model running and are not satisfied with it's performance, would I start to look into time series models.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my post and cleared some problem, can you help me?

Comment: Hi, yeah. I would take a look of what data I have, and, as Nikolas suggested, try some anomaly detection. I'm pretty sure even a hand-crafted one would work very well, as your site is probably quite small yet, and probably not many people have tried writing bots. 

So, plot histograms of reaction time; plot histograms of average session length; Average player aggression, such as raise %, etc. etc. Find like 10 players you personally are sure are bots and 10 you are sure are human. Write rules, which classify most bots as bots and most humans as humans.